# Getting Encrypted CAS User through serviceValidate

Tags: cas

I am using oauth2.0 to get service token from CAS server. When trying to validate token using

/cas/serviceValidate url getting response

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
        <cas:user>JJuH5FMVz6Lsq+4xwIpe39iCZx0=</cas:user>
    </cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

where user is in encrypted format. I know that may user/pass is admin/admin. How can we identify user or encryption technique used.

Thanks,